# PHP check if any array value is not a string or numeric?

Tags: php, arrays, string, validation, array-filter

I have an array of values and I'd like to check that all values are either string or numeric. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Currently I'm just checking for strings so I was just doing `if (array_filter($arr, 'is_string') ===  $arr)` which seems to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See: PHP's [is_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) and [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) functions.

Combined with `array_filter`, you can then compare the two arrays to see if they are equal.

```
function isStringOrNumeric($in) {
// Return true if $in is either a string or numeric
   return is_string($in) || is_numeric($in);
}

class Test{}

$a = array( 'one', 2, 'three', new Test());
$b = array_filter($a, 'isStringOrNumeric');

if($b === $a)
    echo('Success!');
else
    echo('Fail!');
```

Comment: Would be great if he needed to have data on each field individually, but quite inefficient when you just need one value for whole array, isn't it?

Comment: My apologies, read the question wrong.  I have updated it to use the array_filter, but I still think this solution will iterate through the array twice (but I believe is unavoidable)

Comment: I understand the logic of your function, but I think lots of programmers forgot "old ways" to think in procedural way and with sequence approach to things. Take a look at my answer, honestly tell me what don't you like about it.

Comment: Absolutely nothing, it's a perfectly valid solution.

Comment: I don't understand your (his) solution, why trying to use `array_filter` and compare whole array `O(2n)` when you can have `O(n)` without any problems... I don't mean to troll or insult you I just want to understand what's better on your way and reason why you choose this way (or whether you just wanted to change his code as little as possible).

Answer (score 7):

More effective would be this:

```php
function isStringNumberArray( $array){
  foreach( $array as $val){
    if( !is_string( $val) && !is_numeric( $val)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

This method:

- won't create new array
- will stop after first invalid value

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to do a single run through the array, you could write your own function to check each of the values against your specific criteria. Something like:

```
function is_string_or_numeric($var)
{
    return is_string($var) || is_numeric($var);
}
```

Then you can filter your array like:

```
if (array_filter($arr, 'is_string_or_numeric') === $arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's ctype functions, specifically `ctype_alpha()` and `ctype_digit()` are also worth looking at:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on what you mean by "either string or numeric" (this could mean `is_numeric(X)`, or `is_int(X) || is_string(X)`, or any number of other things).  Probably the most efficient way (though it's more verbose) is this:

```
public function isValid(array $array) {
    $valid = TRUE;

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (!is_int($value) && !is_string($value)) {
            $valid = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers for this one.  If you want to use the method you've been using, you will want to write your own function for this.

so for each element in the array you are going to check if it is a number:

```
function isNumber($array_element) {
    return is_numeric($array_element);
}
```

and then call that test function using `array_filter`

```
if (array_filter($arr, 'is_number')  {
  // is a number code here.
}
```

Have you written a function 'is_string()'?  If not, `array_filter($arr, 'is_string')` may not be working the way you think it is.).

Comment: Wouldn't you acheive the same thing with less code if you just ran if(array_filter($arr, 'is_numeric') instead of creating a new function.

Comment: Seems off-topic to me

Answer (score 0):

Two facts:

- foreach is faster than array_map(), because it doesnt call a function on each iteration
- using the === Operator is faster than is_int / is_string, like so:

  `if ((int)$value === $value) echo "its an int";`

  `if ((string)$value === $value) echo "its a string";`